# web application configuration in spring using xml

Tags: java, xml, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc

**I am trying to connect mongodb using spring configuration xml for web application while running this application Database is connecting properly but I am facing below error please help me to sort out this problem.**

**error:**

```
WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/login/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
 <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/views/home.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**servlet-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
        infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.excelit.singup" />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
        up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/login/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
        in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>
<!--    <beans:beans profile="local">
        <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:mongo.properties" />
    </beans:beans> -->

    <beans:beans>
<mongo:mongo host="192.168.1.7" port="27017"></mongo:mongo>
    <mongo:db-factory dbname="admin" />
<beans:bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
<beans:constructor-arg ref="mongo"></beans:constructor-arg>
<beans:constructor-arg value="admin"></beans:constructor-arg>
</beans:bean>
<mongo:repositories base-package="com.excelit.singup"></mongo:repositories>
</beans:beans>
</beans:beans>
```

Comment: This question  is not duplicate because, My configuration is in  xml file not in java class

Comment: can you add your controller's code here?